# Can I replace these NPN/PNP transistors with N/P-MOS in this power regulator?

Tags: power-supply, powermosfet

I know MOSFETs are not a direct replacement for BJT (although I have read otherwise anyway), so I'm interested in know if this could be done, despite any redesign if needed. In this power regulator, I have added power BJT so the load can get all the current the transformer can provide. My problem is that I don't have access to PNP BJT. This is a hobby project, I'm reusing parts from discarded electronics like old CRT computer monitors. Non of these came with PNP power BJT. However, I have a piece of PCB that came with pairs of N and P mosfets (IRF630 and FQP17P06). Would be very good if I can use these instead of BJT, because I only have NPN BJT, and I guess these can't be used in the negative regulator.

[image]

More:

Voltage after rectification is 30 V. Load would consume about 2 A x 4 (each TDA2050 chipamp says consumes 1.5 A, and want to use 4). So 8 A at max sound volume. Transformer has a label saying 30-0-30 VAC / 10 A. I need a way to bypass high current to regulated voltage, this is usually done by using NPN and PNP BJT. All this because TDA2050 cant operate with more than 25 VDC or says its datasheet.

Comment: nitpick: you're using "transistor" when you mean BJT. MOSFETs are a type of transistor (that's what the T stands for!).

Comment: Fixed...sorry I'm not an electronics engineer, just a hobbyst

Comment: The way it is drawn, you can replace them with diodes with no change to the functionality (or lack thereof). Probably there is an error with D1/D2.

Comment: Show the voltage at the rectifier bridge, as FET VGS is typically larger than  BJT VBE, and would need redesign to handle. Add the output current you need, as FET's are typically only rated for switching operation, not continuous 'linear' high power dissipation, and need to be run waaaaay below the dissipation you might infer from the data sheet. The clue is whether the SOA graph has a 'DC' line. Link to your data sheets. You can build a 'power PNP' with a power NPN and a signal power level PNP in a Sziklai pair, and drop that straight into your schematic.

Comment: D1 ,D2 are wrong and they should be reversed for the question to get good answers.

Comment: At 30 VAC out, you need to burn a whopping (30*1.41-25)*8=138 W in each regulator. You’ll be much better off unwinding a few turns off the secondary on the transformer or get another one more suited for the job in the first place. Moreover, +-25 V is the absolute max the IC can take. You can’t design for this voltage as nominal. The IC will fry.

Comment: To see the circuit layout for increased current capability, have a look at a datasheet for 78xx regulators, e.g., the "Application information" section of [Datasheet - L78 - Positive voltage regulator ICs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf). It'd be a good idea to have a look at the rest of the datasheet too, in case they mention any important considerations when using those regulators.

Comment: "Voltage after rectification is 30 V." Did you measure this or is this only a theoretical expectation? AC is usually specified as RMS voltage, not peak, so I would expect the rectified voltage of a transformer labelled 30 VAC to be about 40 V.

Comment: You may not need a regulated supply for the power amp section, just for the pre-amp, if you can keep the ripple to maybe 0.5 V RMS, because it has some "supply voltage rejection"—see the "Electrical characteristics section of the datasheet and chapter 9, "Power supples and PSRR", of *Audio Power Amplifier Design Handbook* by Douglas Self.

Answer (score 8):

I'll talk about MOSFETs in a moment, but for now your biggest problem here is not the transistors, it's the capacitors.

Firstly, those big 1000μF caps on the output side are likely to destabilise the regulators. You should be relying on the regulators to regulate, not on capacitors. I recommend moving them to the left of the regulators, to the input side, in parallel with the caps over there, since they need as much help as they can get.

Between full-wave rectified "top-up pulses", output current must come from the capacitors. When drawing 8A from a 1000μF capacitor, the capacitor will completely discharge in less than 10ms.

The 7824 will need *at least* +27V input to regulate properly, which means that you cannot allow the voltage across those caps to drop below that level. Given +30V of rectified DC, This implies a maximum input ripple of 3V peak-to-peak.

<sub>Note: In your design it's worse than that, since the bipolar transistor will need nearly +25V at its base, to produce +24V at the emitter, which means the 7824 will drop-out even sooner.</sub>

The largest current you can draw from 1000μF such that its potential difference changes by only 3V is about:

$$ I = \frac{C \cdot \Delta V}{\Delta t} = \frac{1000\mu F \times 3V}{10ms} = 300mA $$

Clearly that's way below the 8A you need from this circuit, by a factor of 27. To be able to obtain a clean 24V output, under a load of 8A, you will require well over 20,000μF of capacitance at the input (these are only rough figures):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN9aMX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Also, such a large capacitance will incur significant inrush current, which you should probably try to mitigate somehow.

---

As for the use of MOSFETs, sure you can use them. The 7824 output is the limiting factor here. With these external pass transistors the 7824 is under very little load, but still can't output more than a volt or so below its input. So if the input drops to +27V, the greatest output you can expect from the regulator itself is +26V. Again, this is back-of-the-envelope stuff, maybe the regulator can do better, maybe worse.

So your concern then is to ensure that +26V at the gate of the MOSFET is sufficiently high to turn it on, when the source is at +24V. In other words \$V_{GS(ON)} < (26V - 24V) \$. In practice, \$V_{GS(ON)}\$ should be more like 1.5V (or less), since \$V_{GS(ON)}\$ is a threshold at which the channel is only partially conductive.

The on-resistance \$R_{DS(ON)}\$ is going to be important too. For example, with \$R_{DS(ON)}=0.1\Omega\$, at 8A you can expect \$V_{DS} = 0.1\Omega \times 8 = 0.8V\$, which will make it even harder to achieve a sufficiently high gate potential.

---

You want 24V out, but that's too close to the 30V DC supply to be practical:

- Smoothing capacitance will have to be huge to keep ripple small enough to avoid regulator drop-out.
- The regulator is always operating close to drop-out, a problem exacerbated by the need for it to output *significantly more than 24V* in order to drive the transistor base/gate.
- A MOSFET pass transistor will have to have extremely low \$V_{GS(ON)}\$. By comparison a BJT will need only \$V_{BE} = 0.8V\$.

You can make the problem electrically simpler by requiring an output significantly less than 24V, perhaps 20V or 15V, for example. But then you have increased power dissipation in the pass elements, and you have thermal issues to address. This is the eternal struggle we have with linear power supplies.

There's probably more to say, but I think that's enough. Sorry that the news isn't better.

Comment: Excellent answer, but note that you're basing this on the asker's assertion that the rectified voltage is 30 V. Usually a transformer label '30-0-30 VAC' means 30 VAC RMS though, not peak. It is possible that the rectified voltage is about 40 V (30xsqrt(2) - 2x0,7 = 40,9 V).

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the 30V down to 23V with bipolar transistors results in 25W from an old TDA2050 into 8 ohms or 40W into 4 ohms with low distortion. Mosfets cannot be used instead.
The old TDA2050 is about 60% efficient so 8 x 40W= 320W from the power supply driving 8 ohm speakers or 620W when driving 4 ohm speakers.
Is it for a stadium?

Comment: Interesting answer that pulls me back to the draw board. My objective here is to build, as hobby, a stereo power amplifier I will use at my workshop (about 8 x 8 m place). Sometimes I feel enthusiastic with my doings and pop up the volume quite a bit. Now you suggest 4 x TDA2050 will be overkill? So with only 2, one per channel I would get plenty? Because if so, it will be great :) I was told in other forums, these 2050 are wimpies, that's what I thought about BTL them.

Answer (score 1):

FETs have higher Vgs (several volts) versus bipolar transistor Vbe (0.5-0.6V), so if you use the FET as a follower as in the above schematic, the minimum dropout voltage of your regulator will be pretty high.

> Voltage after rectification is 30 V. Transformer has a label saying 30-0-30 VAC / 10 A

If it's a 30V AC transformer, then that's the RMS voltage, and peak is 1.4x that. So you should be getting at least 40V on your caps. If that is not the case, something's wrong somewhere. Maybe it's the label, or the diodes, or the caps.

In any case you need a lot more than 1000µF on the input if you want to draw 6A max. How much depends on the actual voltage at the output of the transformer. If it actually outputs 30V DC post-bridge under load, then you need about 15000µF.

Since you have NMOS and PMOS, I'd just make a LDO:

[image]

This is one of the simplest PMOS LDO. The 4 bipolar transistors are small signal types like 3904/3906 or whatever you've got. You need a 12V reference like a TL431 or a Zener diode.

The FET's gate is current driven from the output of the LTP which means open loop gain varies depending on FET Gm(Iout) and Vds. This is on purpose: when the FET gets squeezed in low dropout conditions, it gets slower, and open loop gain drops too, which keeps it stable.

Add 100µF to 1000µF cap on the output, ESR 0.1-1 ohm.

For the negative version, you can flip the schematic around and change all component polarities... or realize it's an opamp after all, so it can be made inverting. The top half makes +24V, the bottom half uses that as reference input to make -24V.

[image]

There is no short circuit or overheating protection.

Output caps include RLC models, that doesn't mean you have to add the inductors! They represent the caps' inductance for simulation. You'll probably need a 100nF+1-2 ohms snubber at the output, so R17 and R18 should exist.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that most Mosfet (the newest, the worse) are not intended to work in linear zone hence not appropriate for linear regulators. Have a look at SOA graph.